# Overwriting files in geodatabase outside workspace environment using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, workspace

I initially set the workspace environment to a directory and included the option, arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True, but at some point in my script, I convert a shapefile in that directory to a geodatabase file. When I do this, I get the error:

> File (filename) already exists.

I assume that because the overwriteOutput option is specified for the workspace, it doesn't apply to the geodatabase within that directory. However, I also tried to change the environment to the geodatabase and set the overwrite option to true again. The error remained.

How can I fix this (without deleting the file)?

Comment: Can you paste your code? And are you doing this within ArcMap, or as a standalone python script?

Comment: In a geodatabase you can't have anything be the same name. So if you already have a point feature class called "something", then a polygon feature class cannot be called "something." Same for a table and feature class. If you are able to overwrite, it could just be you have a something in your geodatabase already called the same name but of a different type.

Comment: I'm doing this with a standalone python script. I checked that there weren't other files with the same name. I didn't know that geodatabases couldn't contain multiple files of different types but with the same name, so thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the file you don't want, and delete it.  Something like:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\temp\mydb.gdb"

if arcpy.Exists("fcToOverwrite"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("fcToOverwrite")

# your convert shapefile code here
```

See [Exists - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/exists.htm).